# restore my system

Tags: restore

I faced a problem since I've run the commands in [link](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6942#:%7E:text=on%20Aug%2018-,I%20know,-this%20is%20a) to upgrade from ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS to 20.04. Unfortunately, I couldn't upgrade. Besides, running those commands broke other things from running.

Can I somehow restore the previous state of my system before running those commands so that my system works well like before?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131817/discussion-on-question-by-mar-z-restore-my-system).

Answer (score 2):

My guess was you've upgraded packages and are no longer running *bionic* (18.04) but have yet to boot - but in that case I'd still reboot & assess what you're actually running & how the upgrade went...

If Ubuntu (or flavor) Desktop you can fix by re-installing (no-format) which is what I'd likely do if I wasn't sure exactly what was done (I'm not sure!)

```
guiverc@d960-ubu2:/usr/share/sddm/themes/lubuntu$   rmadison update-manager-core
 update-manager-core | 1:0.196.11    | trusty           | all
 update-manager-core | 1:0.196.25    | trusty-updates   | all
 update-manager-core | 1:16.04.3     | xenial           | all
 update-manager-core | 1:16.04.12    | xenial-security  | all
 update-manager-core | 1:16.04.17    | xenial-updates   | all
 update-manager-core | 1:18.04.11    | bionic           | all
 update-manager-core | 1:18.04.11.13 | bionic-updates   | all
 update-manager-core | 1:18.04.11.14 | bionic-proposed  | all
 update-manager-core | 1:20.04.9     | focal            | all
 update-manager-core | 1:20.04.10.9  | focal-updates    | all
 update-manager-core | 1:21.04.8     | hirsute          | all
 update-manager-core | 1:21.04.10    | hirsute-updates  | all
 update-manager-core | 1:21.04.11    | hirsute-proposed | all
 update-manager-core | 1:21.10.4     | impish           | all
 update-manager-core | 1:21.10.5     | impish-updates   | all
 update-manager-core | 1:22.04.2     | jammy            | all
```

If you `apt-cache policy update-manager-core you should get` update-manager-core | 1:18.04.11.13 | bionic-updates   | all`if your system is *bionic* but I suspect you'll get a package more like`update-manager-core | 1:21.04.8     | hirsute          | all`(which would match the *hirsute* lines you pasted in your question) but if you'd gone where you wanted (*focal* or 20.04) you'd see`update-manager-core | 1:20.04.10.9  | focal-updates    | all`.... ie. you're not running 18.04 at all I believe; the text file of your release doesn't match what you're actually running. I'd explore using`apt-cache`,` ubuntu-security-status` etc

Also note:  In comments I asked you to run `ubuntu-support-status` which is the *bionic* command but you got

> I get this : "ubuntu-support-status: command not found" and
> "ubuntu-security-status" runs

which is more *confirmation* that you're not running *bionic* with more packages upgraded. Instead your system ran the command which didn't yet exist in 2018; ie. the re-write called `ubuntu-security-status`.

[Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/) reaches the end of it's *standard* support life in 2023-April; ie. 5 years from release. Any packages you have of that release will show that as the end of your security updates; though do note 'universe' packages had 3 yeas of support which has already ended for *bionic*.  `ubuntu-security-status` (or if using 18.04 it's `ubuntu-support-status`) will give a glimpse of what packages you've likely got (*it may not be accurate; but it's an easy way of getting a glimpse of packages that need fixing instead of checking them individually*). It might be a lot of work I suspect; why re-installs are usually done, or restoration of our backups.

Much of what you've suggested will only *fix* your pasted detail on the screen; however it will stop your system getting updates & make it insecure in day(s) instead of month(s). The package I highlighted before shows you've already got hirsute packages installed (`1:20.04.10.9`); they won't receive any updates and *bionic* updates (`1:18.04.11.13`) as even if a newer `1:18.04.11.14` came out; 18.04.. is not > 20.04... so that package & all your upgraded *hirsute* packages will require you to manually fix. Your system isn't *bionic* or 18.04 anymore. Restore your backups (*it's why we create/have them*), re-install or re-install each package manually.

Summary

- restore your system backups
- re-install; which is easy for Desktops (I use it myself at least weekly in QA-testing & rather regularly in changing releases as focus changes to a different release (eg. currently *jammy* [22.04] & *focal* [20.04.4] are my primary focus) and my Ubuntu packages are re-installed without loss of any data files.
- manually fix as I've alluded to... this may be a *huge* job so I'd avoid it; re-install is much easier & cleaner.

*This is written based on details you've provided; only two packages have been proven to be hirsute, but that's two of only two looked at - ie. a tiny sample size, but  I suspect it's far more than that obviously. You can read the output of the commands I've given, explore using `apt-cache policy` suggested earlier for random packages & draw your own conclusion which will confirm or other my suspicions*

Comment: large parts of this taken from comments; it's still messy, but loads of comments skipped

Comment: Sorry I have minimal experience trying to install Ubuntu (server or desktop) remotely.  I'm largely a desktop user, and whilst I've performed an install within the last 30 mins (QA-test) it was local so I can see the screen & notice issues etc.  I do have & have used server boxes that allow the install to be done remotely (using ILO, IDRAC...) but I haven't used that in some time..  The servers were only a few floors away if I made a mistake though..

Comment: Thank you. I try.