# upgrading wrongly from ubuntu 18.04.6LTS to 21

Tags: apt, upgrade

I tried to upgrade my system from ubuntu 18.04.6LTS (bionic) to 20.04 LTS (focal).
But I ran some commands related to upgrading to Ubuntu 21.04, which were completely irrelevant to my goal. The commands I ran are as follow:

```
sudo sed -i 's/bionic/**hirsute**/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo sed -i 's/bionic/**hirsute**/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
sudo apt update
```

Seemingly some of the packages are upgraded to '21'. How can I fix this? My goal is to have an LTS release.

By running `dpkg -l > /tmp/somefile` output of `/tmp/somefile` is as follow, I pasted some part of it. It doesn't allow me to paste it all.

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                                        Version                                             Architecture Description
+++-===========================================================-===================================================-============-===============================================================================
ii  a11y-profile-manager-indicator                              0.1.11-0ubuntu4                                     amd64        Accessibility Profile Manager - Unity desktop indicator
ii  account-plugin-facebook                                     0.12+16.04.20160126-0ubuntu1                        all          GNOME Control Center account plugin for single signon - facebook
ii  account-plugin-flickr                                       0.12+16.04.20160126-0ubuntu1                        all          GNOME Control Center account plugin for single signon - flickr
ii  account-plugin-google                                       0.12+16.04.20160126-0ubuntu1                        all          GNOME Control Center account plugin for single signon
ii  accountsservice                                             0.6.45-1ubuntu1.3                                   amd64        query and manipulate user account information
ii  acl                                                         2.2.52-3build1                                      amd64        Access control list utilities
ii  acpi-support                                                0.142                                               amd64        scripts for handling many ACPI events
ii  acpid                                                       1:2.0.28-1ubuntu1                                   amd64        Advanced Configuration and Power Interface event daemon
ii  activity-log-manager                                        0.9.7-0ubuntu26                                     amd64        blacklist configuration user interface for Zeitgeist
ii  adduser                                                     3.118ubuntu5                                        all          add and remove users and groups
ii  adium-theme-ubuntu                                          0.3.4-0ubuntu4                                      all          Adium message style for Ubuntu
ii  adwaita-icon-theme                                          3.28.0-1ubuntu1                                     all          default icon theme of GNOME (small subset)
ii  aglfn                                                       1.7-3                                               all          Adobe Glyph List For New Fonts
ii  aisleriot                                                   1:3.22.5-1                                          amd64        GNOME solitaire card game collection
ii  alsa-base                                                   1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5                                all          ALSA driver configuration files
ii  alsa-utils                                                  1.1.3-1ubuntu1                                      amd64        Utilities for configuring and using ALSA
ii  amd64-microcode                                             3.20191021.1+really3.20181128.1~ubuntu0.18.04.1     amd64        Processor microcode firmware for AMD CPUs
ii  anacron                                                     2.3-24                                              amd64        cron-like program that doesn't go by time
ii  apache2-bin                                                 2.4.29-1ubuntu4.19                                  amd64        Apache HTTP Server (modules and other binary files)
ii  apg                                                         2.2.3.dfsg.1-5                                      amd64        Automated Password Generator - Standalone version
ii  app-install-data                                            15.10                                               all          Ubuntu applications (data files)
ii  app-install-data-partner                                    16.04                                               all          Application Installer (data files for partner applications/repositories)
ii  apparmor                                                    2.12-4ubuntu5.1                                     amd64        user-space parser utility for AppArmor
ii  appmenu-qt:amd64                                            0.2.7+14.04.20140305-0ubuntu2                       amd64        application menu for Qt
rc  appmenu-qt5                                                 0.3.0+16.04.20170216-0ubuntu1                       amd64        application menu for Qt5
ii  apport                                                      2.20.9-0ubuntu7.27                                  all          automatically generate crash reports for debugging
ii  apport-gtk                                                  2.20.9-0ubuntu7.27                                  all          GTK+ frontend for the apport crash report system
ii  apport-symptoms                                             0.20                                                all          symptom scripts for apport
ii  appstream                                                   0.12.0-3ubuntu1                                     amd64        Software component metadata management
ii  apt                                                         1.6.14                                              amd64        commandline package manager
ii  apt-config-icons                                            0.12.0-3ubuntu1                                     all          APT configuration snippet to enable icon downloads
rc  apt-show-versions                                           0.22.7ubuntu1                                       all          lists available package versions with distribution
ii  apt-transport-https                                         1.6.14                                              all          transitional package for https support
ii  apt-utils                                                   1.6.14                                              amd64        package management related utility programs
ii  aptdaemon                                                   1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu19.5                            all          transaction based package management service
ii  aptdaemon-data                                              1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu19.5                            all          data files for clients
ii  aptitude                                                    0.8.10-6ubuntu1                                     amd64        terminal-based package manager
ii  aptitude-common                                             0.8.10-6ubuntu1                                     all          architecture independent files for the aptitude package manager
ii  apturl                                                      0.5.2ubuntu14.2                                     amd64        install packages using the apt protocol - GTK+ frontend
ii  apturl-common                                               0.5.2ubuntu14.2                                     amd64        install packages using the apt protocol - common data
ii  aspell                                                      0.60.7~20110707-4ubuntu0.2                          amd64        GNU Aspell spell-checker
ii  aspell-en                                                   2017.08.24-0-0.1                                    all          English dictionary for GNU Aspell
ii  at-spi2-core                                                2.28.0-1                                            amd64        Assistive Technology Service Provider Interface (dbus core)
ii  atril                                                       1.20.1-2ubuntu2                                     amd64        MATE document viewer
ii  atril-common                                                1.20.1-2ubuntu2                                     all          MATE document viewer (common files)
ii  autoconf                                                    2.69-11                                             all          automatic configure script builder
ii  automake                                                    1:1.15.1-3ubuntu2                                   all          Tool for generating GNU Standards-compliant Makefiles
ii  autotools-dev                                               20180224.1                                          all          Update infrastructure for config.{guess,sub} files
ii  avahi-autoipd                                               0.7-3.1ubuntu1.3                                    amd64        Avahi IPv4LL network address configuration daemon
ii  avahi-daemon                                                0.7-3.1ubuntu1.3                                    amd64        Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD daemon
ii  avahi-utils                                                 0.7-3.1ubuntu1.3                                    amd64        Avahi browsing, publishing and discovery utilities
ii  bamfdaemon                                                  0.5.3+18.04.20180207.2-0ubuntu1                     amd64        Window matching library - daemon
ii  baobab                                                      3.28.0-1                                            amd64        GNOME disk usage analyzer
ii  base-files                                                  10.1ubuntu2.11                                      amd64        Debian base system miscellaneous files
ii  base-passwd                                                 3.5.44                                              amd64        Debian base system master password and group files
ii  bash                                                        4.4.18-2ubuntu1.2                                   amd64        GNU Bourne Again SHell
ii  bash-completion                                             1:2.8-1ubuntu1                                      all          programmable completion for the bash shell
ii  bc                                                          1.07.1-2                                            amd64        GNU bc arbitrary precision calculator language
ii  bind9-host                                                  1:9.11.3+dfsg-1ubuntu1.16                           amd64        DNS lookup utility (deprecated)
ii  binutils                                                    2.36.1-6ubuntu1                                     amd64        GNU assembler, linker and binary utilities
ii  binutils-common:amd64                                       2.36.1-6ubuntu1                                     amd64        Common files for the GNU assembler, linker and binary utilities
ii  binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu                                   2.36.1-6ubuntu1                                     amd64        GNU binary utilities, for x86-64-linux-gnu target
ii  blt                                                         2.5.3+dfsg-4                                        amd64        graphics extension library for Tcl/Tk - run-time
ii  bluez                                                       5.48-0ubuntu3.6                                     amd64        Bluetooth tools and daemons
ii  bluez-cups                                                  5.48-0ubuntu3.6                                     amd64        Bluetooth printer driver for CUPS
ii  bluez-obexd                                                 5.48-0ubuntu3.6                                     amd64        bluez obex daemon
ii  bolt                                                        0.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                                amd64        system daemon to manage thunderbolt 3 devices
ii  branding-ubuntu                                             0.10                                                all          Replacement artwork with Ubuntu branding
ii  brltty                                                      5.5-4ubuntu2.0.1                                    amd64        Access software for a blind person using a braille display
ii  bsdmainutils                                                11.1.2ubuntu1                                       amd64        collection of more utilities from FreeBSD
ii  bsdutils                                                    1:2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.7                               amd64        basic utilities from 4.4BSD-Lite
ii  bubblewrap                                                  0.2.1-1ubuntu0.1                                    amd64        setuid wrapper for unprivileged chroot and namespace manipulation
ii  build-essential                                             12.4ubuntu1                                         amd64        Informational list of build-essential packages
ii  busybox-initramfs                                           1:1.30.1-6ubuntu2                                   amd64        Standalone shell setup for initramfs
ii  busybox-static                                              1:1.27.2-2ubuntu3.3                                 amd64        Standalone rescue shell with tons of builtin utilities
ii  bzip2                                                       1.0.8-4ubuntu3                                      amd64        high-quality block-sorting file compressor - utilities
ii  bzip2-doc                                                   1.0.6-8.1ubuntu0.2                                  all          high-quality block-sorting file compressor - documentation
ii  ca-certificates                                             20210119ubuntu0.21.04.1                             all          Common CA certificates
ii  ca-certificates-java                                        20180516ubuntu1~18.04.1                             all          Common CA certificates (JKS keystore)
ii  caja                                                        1.20.2-4ubuntu1                                     amd64        file manager for the MATE desktop
ii  caja-common                                                 1.20.2-4ubuntu1                                     all          file manager for the MATE desktop (common files)
ii  checkinstall                                                1.6.2-4ubuntu2                                      amd64        installation tracker
ii  cheese                                                      3.28.0-1ubuntu1                                     amd64        tool to take pictures and videos from your webcam
ii  cheese-common                                               3.28.0-1ubuntu1                                     all          Common files for the Cheese tool to take pictures and videos
ii  cmake                                                       3.10.2-1ubuntu2.18.04.2                             amd64        cross-platform, open-source make system
ii  cmake-data                                                  3.10.2-1ubuntu2.18.04.2                             all          CMake data files (modules, templates and documentation)
ii  cockpit                                                     215-1~ubuntu18.04.1                                 all          Web Console for Linux servers
ii  cockpit-bridge                                              215-1~ubuntu18.04.1                                 amd64        Cockpit bridge server-side component
ii  cockpit-dashboard                                           215-1~ubuntu18.04.1                                 all          Cockpit remote servers and dashboard
ii  cockpit-networkmanager                                      215-1~ubuntu18.04.1                                 all          Cockpit user interface for networking
ii  cockpit-packagekit                                          215-1~ubuntu18.04.1                                 all          Cockpit user interface for packages
ii  cockpit-storaged                                            215-1~ubuntu18.04.1                                 all          Cockpit user interface for storage
ii  cockpit-system                                              215-1~ubuntu18.04.1                                 all          Cockpit admin interface for a system
ii  cockpit-ws                                                  215-1~ubuntu18.04.1                                 amd64        Cockpit Web Service
ii  colord                                                      1.3.3-2build1                                       amd64        system service to manage device colour profiles -- system daemon
ii  colord-data                                                 1.3.3-2build1                                       all          system service to manage device colour profiles -- data files
ii  command-not-found                                           18.04.5                                             all          Suggest installation of packages in interactive bash sessions
ii  command-not-found-data                                      18.04.5                                             amd64        Set of data files for command-not-found.
ii  compiz                                                      1:0.9.13.1+18.04.20180302-0ubuntu1                  all          OpenGL window and compositing manager
ii  compiz-core                                                 1:0.9.13.1+18.04.20180302-0ubuntu1                  amd64        OpenGL window and compositing manager
ii  compiz-gnome                                                1:0.9.13.1+18.04.20180302-0ubuntu1                  amd64        OpenGL window and compositing manager - GNOME window decorator
ii  compiz-plugins-default:amd64                                1:0.9.13.1+18.04.20180302-0ubuntu1                  amd64        OpenGL window and compositing manager - default plugins
ii  console-setup                                               1.201ubuntu2                                        all          console font and keymap setup program
ii  console-setup-linux                                         1.201ubuntu2                                        all          Linux specific part of console-setup
ii  coreutils                                                   8.28-1ubuntu1                                       amd64        GNU core utilities
ii  cpio                                                        2.12+dfsg-6ubuntu0.18.04.4                          amd64        GNU cpio -- a program to manage archives of files
ii  cpp                                                         4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3                                  amd64        GNU C preprocessor (cpp)
ii  cpp-4.8                                                     4.8.5-4ubuntu8                                      amd64        GNU C preprocessor
ii  cpp-4.9                                                     4.9.4-2ubuntu1~16.04                                amd64        GNU C preprocessor
ii  cpp-5                                                       5.5.0-12ubuntu1                                     amd64        GNU C preprocessor
ii  cpp-6                                                       6.5.0-2ubuntu1~18.04                                amd64        GNU C preprocessor
ii  cpp-7                                                       7.5.0-6ubuntu4                                      amd64        GNU C preprocessor
ii  cpufrequtils                                                008-1build1                                         amd64        utilities to deal with the cpufreq Linux kernel feature
ii  cracklib-runtime                                            2.9.2-5build1                                       amd64        runtime support for password checker library cracklib2
ii  crda                                                        3.18-1build1                                        amd64        wireless Central Regulatory Domain Agent
ii  cron                                                        3.0pl1-128.1ubuntu1                                 amd64        process scheduling daemon
rc  cuda-command-line-tools-9-0                                 9.0.176-1                                           amd64        CUDA command-line tools
rc  cuda-core-9-0                                               9.0.176-1                                           amd64        CUDA core tools
```

Some part of output of `apt list --installed | awk '{print $1}' | egrep -v bionic`

```
a11y-profile-manager-indicator/hirsute,now
account-plugin-facebook/now
account-plugin-flickr/now
account-plugin-google/now
accountsservice/now
acl/now
acpi-support/now
acpid/now
activity-log-manager/now
adduser/hirsute,hirsute,now
adium-theme-ubuntu/hirsute,hirsute,now
adwaita-icon-theme/now
aglfn/now
aisleriot/now
alsa-base/now
alsa-utils/now
amd64-microcode/now
anacron/now
apache2-bin/now
```

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132815/discussion-on-question-by-mar-z-upgrading-wrongly-from-ubuntu-18-04-6lts-to-21).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [restore my system](https://askubuntu.com/q/1377623/)

Answer (score 2):

**See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1373514/can-there-be-any-issue-if-i-edit-sources-list-and-jump-between-ubuntu-releases) Asked by me, here, you will find out what things you have done wrong**

**FYI:** *the update error is because the bionic beaver has some repositories which were removed from hirsute, removing those repositories and running apt upgrade will work*

**FYI**: *Don't do these types of things, please, You  <s>cannot</s>  should not upgrade to a non-LTS release from LTS release (You are upgrading 18.04 to 21.04!!)*

First, disable all PPAs before proceeding(`sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* $HOME`)

As you mentioned in the question, you want an LTS release

Currently, 20.04 is the latest LTS release, but you have already changed a few packages to hirsute. Thus, you <s>cannot</s> should not upgrade to 20.04 (As a few packages will be downgraded and downgrading is unsecured and may break the system or make some packages unusable)

Let us upgrade to hirsute (a none LTS release)

First, change the contents of `sources.list`* to

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute-security main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute partner
```

After that run `sudo apt update`

I don't think so It will say any errors

After this run this

```
sudo snap refresh 
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* $HOME
sudo apt dist-upgrade && sudo apt full-upgrade
```

You are done! It will work

---

*- `sources.list` is available in `/etc/apt/`, the full path is `/etc/apt/sources.list`. `man sources.list` will also help .

Comment: Sorry, Is it for upgrading to ubuntu 21 (hirsute)? I'd like an LTS release.

Comment: I read a question again, so really I'm a bit scared by `update-manager-core` @ 21.04.10 version. So it is semi-upgraded 18.04 system with parts of 21.04. Downgrading packages is difficult task. So in current situation it is better to leave things as they are. @Marz, so you use hirsute repositories, then optionally upgrade it to 21.10 and wait for 22.04 LTS.

Comment: 18.04 LTS and 20.04 LTS are the only supported LTS releases available.  21.04 and 21.10 are not LTS. There is also no such thing as "Ubuntu 21". There are two releases from 2021: 21.04 and 21.10-- they are entirely different releases. If you are going to be specific in this way, make sure you use the actual version numbers for the releases.

Answer (score 0):

Okay we can try something.

First make a backup from your personal data!!And draw an iso for focal and make an bootable usb-stick/dvd.
We try to revert packages to bionic version first.
remove any ppa file in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
Make a clean /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
```

Now the tricky part.

Create `/etc/apt/preferences.d/bionic.pref`

```
Package: *
Pin: release v=18.04, a=bionic-security
Pin-Priority:1001

Package: *
Pin: release v=18.04,a=bionic-updates
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: *
Pin: release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: *
Pin: release v=18.04,o=Canonical,a=bionic,n=bionic,c=partner 
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

Now run

```
sudo apt update && apt -s upgrade
```

the last is only a simulation. No errors

```
sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt full-upgrade
```

It can work, but it might not.

Check in `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`
that

```
Prompt=lts
```

is set!!

```
sudo apt install apt-show-versions
```

Now we remove no longer available packages.
first overview which packages are this.

```
apt-show-versions | egrep avail  | awk '{print $1}'
apt -s remove $(apt-show-versions | egrep avail  | awk '{print $1}')
```

This is also a simulation.
This will remove them

```
apt purge $(apt-show-versions | egrep avail  | awk '{print $1}')
```

Remove `/etc/apt/preferences.d/bionic.pref`
then see if

```
do-release-upgrade
```

is working.

I cross fingers.