# How to reinstall ubuntu 20.04 without deleting data

Tags: reinstall

How can I reinstall Ubuntu 20.04 without trashing data
I tried from a Live USB stick but there is not a non-destructive option

Comment: It is very simple. You restore from backup.

Comment: Posting as a comment because I haven't done it myself, but frequent contributor @guiverc often mentions in comments a method to reinstall without losing data.  This may be an answer detailing the method https://askubuntu.com/a/1377810/243321 With luck, they will stop by and give the real lowdown.

Comment: I always have `/home` on its own partition, so I can simply reinstall and tell the installer not to format `/home`.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/591167/resetting-ubuntu-to-factory-settings the answers vary and are general!

Comment: @waltinator the same! And I don't have to deal with any fuzzy. Every OS give the same instructions in their websites and it must be for a reason!

Comment: @waltinator I also use a separate /home partition for the same reason.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Re-install Ubuntu without losing data in home folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/269880/re-install-ubuntu-without-losing-data-in-home-folder)

Comment: "but there is not a non-destructive option" Yes there is: don't pick "format" when mounting